# Mercurial & Text mode in Asset Serialization in Unity3D

Tags: mercurial, unity-game-engine

I use Mercurial in my project and we just switched to "force text" in the Asset Serialization option.

My files are text now, but when I try to merge, I get this `"tool opendiff can't handle binary"` message. I tried to force FileMerge to merge and it marks the whole file as different.

I tried to switch to DiffMerge and force it to merge, and it tells an important info: `"File has a NUL byte at offset 0; this is not valid for encoding..."`

The `file` bash command tells me that those asset files are `"text/plain; charset=us-ascii"`.

`hg diff` between the two revisions results in a YAML text file, so both files are in text mode.

Isn't that a bug? I mean, Unity should convert to text files that merge tools are able to merge...

By the way, we are using Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to convert the project in more than one repository and after merge them.

Somehow it worked when I converted the project on one repo and distributed it to others, that is, no problem in future merges.

The downside is that everybody has to get to the same revision, stop to work and wait for the conversion.